# Can we migrate and keep the same user, taxonomy, and node IDs?

Tags: migrations, 10

When we are migrating a Drupal 7 site to Drupal 10, we have some custom tables which store taxonomy, node, user, and role IDs.

Is their a way to migrate a content type preserving the IDs?

Comment: Yes, you can preserve id, in the migration yml. Just map old id to new id.

Comment: Can you please share the example yml, it would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

The default is to migrate and keep the same ID. Look at web/core/modules/node/migrations/d7_node.yml, and you can see the `nid: tnid` line.

```yaml
id: d7_node
label: Nodes
audit: true
migration_tags:
  - Drupal 7
  - Content
deriver: Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\D7NodeDeriver
source:
  plugin: d7_node
process:
  # If you are using this file to build a custom migration consider removing
  # the nid and vid fields to allow incremental migrations.
  # In D7, nodes always have a tnid, but it's zero for untranslated nodes.
  # We normalize it to equal the nid in that case.
  # @see \Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\source\d7\Node::prepareRow().
  nid: tnid
  vid: vid
  langcode:
    plugin: default_value
    source: language
    default_value: "und"
  title: title
  uid: node_uid
  status: status
  created: created
  changed: changed
  promote: promote
  sticky: sticky
  revision_uid: revision_uid
  revision_log: log
  revision_timestamp: timestamp
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - d7_user
    - d7_node_type
  optional:
    - d7_field_instance
    - d7_comment_field_instance
```

You can also look at d7_user.yml, d7_taxonomy_term.yml, and d7_user_role.yml.

If you do end up needing to customize them, create a custom module, copy the YAML file into my_module/config/install/d7_node.yml and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said: yes you can keep this. And it is the default if you use the core migration templates. It is even mentioned in the inline documentation there.

The examples for user and taxonomy term migrations are a bit cleare than the ones for nodes.

See for example in the core user migration template web/core/modules/user/migrations/d7_user.yml :

```
process:
  # If you are using this file to build a custom migration consider removing
  # the uid field to allow incremental migrations.
  uid: uid
```

And the taxonomy example in web/core/modules/taxonomy/migrations/d7_taxonomy_term.yml :

```
process:
  # If you are using this file to build a custom migration consider removing
  # the tid field to allow incremental migrations.
  tid: tid
```